# Instead of link_to, for linking through image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Just started working on ruby and rails a month ago. Any clues, ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

I included the gem activerecord reputation system into a rails project. The gem works fine and I also tested it manually. Now I want to replace the text for "voting" into icons. As a result the user will click on the icons (thumbs up and down) to vote.

So far I use this:

```
link_to "up", vote_clue_path(clue, type: "up"), method: "post"
```

and what I want is to refactor it and use an icon instead. (The user will click on a thumbs up and thumbs down instead rather than the up and down links).

I have no clue how to do it. Use another method? Refactor it into a new method? Any clue to a new direction would greatly help me.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want an image link you can do something like this

```
=link_to(image_tag("splash_banner.png", :alt => "Home Polish Banner", twitter_link, :target => "_blank")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the block form of link_to

```
<%= link_to vote_clue_path(clue, type: "up"), method: "post" do %>
  <div>Up</div>
<% end %>
```